# Why the variable in the "struct" needs to begin with a capital letter?

Tags: go, syntax

When I was learning “A Tour Of Go”, I found accidently that all the variable names in this "struct" tutorial begin with the capital letter like this:
[a tour of go: more types](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/2)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Vertex{1, 2})
}
```

the "X" and "Y" are in the capital letter.

However, if I use "x" instead "X" in Vertex struct, the program will also give the correct output:
{1 2}

So Is there any difference not to use the variable name with capital letter?

Comment: Just do the whole Tour. (And: The name of the language is just "Go".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the variable in the "struct" needs to begin with a capital letter?

It doesn't *need* to. As you saw yourself, the program still compiled and ran even after you've renamed the fields to lower case. Hence it is *not* a requirement.

> So Is there any difference not to use the variable name with capital letter?

Yes.

---

Identifiers (this includes struct fields) that begin with an upper case letter are `exported`, those that being with a lower case letter or an underscore are `unexported`. This is similar to `private`, `public` access qualifiers in other languages.

- Exported identifiers can be accessed directly by any package that imports the package in which the identifiers were declared.
- Unexported identifiers are directly accessible *only** to the package in which the identifiers were declared.

<sub>*: the `reflect` package has read-only access to unexported fields declared in other packages, which is why `fmt.Println` (which uses `reflect`) was able to print the contents of `Vertex struct{ x, y int }`.</sub>

---

See the official spec: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I still remember I got confused with "public and private method in class" when I was learning C#. I think that I am understood now. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the naming conventions in golang are pretty straight forward, the part with the uppercase refers to the visibility:
"*If an identifier needs to be visible outside the package, its first character should be uppercase. If you don’t have the intention to use it in another package, you can safely stick to mixedCaps.*"